# AChartEngine Chart with dotted stroke legend

Tags: achartengine

In a chart, I have two lines with the same color and what distinguishes them is the dotted stroke on one of them. However, this difference is not visible in the legend (the two lines are solid).

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post a feature request http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/list.